# Page Navigation Controls in Report Viewer Toolbar is not Functioning Properly

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, .net-4.5, reportviewer

I have a working report viewer function in a .net 4.5 Winforms application.  Recently I moved the Form page containing the report viewer control to a separate project in order to load it in it's own AppDomain with LegacyCAS security enabled i.e.:

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory, LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost };
setup.SetCompatibilitySwitches(new[] { "NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy" });
AppDomain _casPolicyEnabledDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Full Trust", null, setup);
try
{
    ReportViewAppDomain.rptSalesReport genSalesReport = (ReportViewAppDomain.rptSalesReport)_casPolicyEnabledDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(typeof(ReportViewAppDomain.rptSalesReport).Assembly.CodeBase, typeof(ReportViewAppDomain.rptSalesReport).FullName);
    bool result = genSalesReport.SalesMonthlyReport_Load(Convert.ToDateTime(startTimePicker.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(endTimePicker.Value), stores, storeIds, depts, deptIds, ParentForm);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //handle exception here
}
```

`genSalesReport.SalesMonthlyReport_Load()` is the call to my Form that generates a report in report viewer local mode.  Since loading this Form in its own AppDomain the numeric textbox of the Report Viewer toolbar page navigation control (see image) does not work. I can type a page number in the textbox but when hitting enter on the keyboard the report viewer does not navigate to the specified page.

[image: report viewer tool bar img]

The page control arrows still work and the page counts and other functions are correct in the navigation control.  I've specified `this.reportViewer1.ShowPageNavigationControls = true;` in the designer file and set focus to the report viewer form page yet the issue still persists.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found this researching my own issue and I suspect it's related. We have our WinForms AcceptButton (the Enter key) wired to the View Report button.  As such we can only ever have Enter trigger "View Report" or the page navigation, not both. We have to turn off the View-Report-Trigger after the report is rendered the first time or the navigation buttons won't work. Recommend checking the Form that hosts the report to see if you have your Enter Key double-booked.